# Why is the camera not rotating to face the first waypoint?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the game starts, a random waypoint is selected from an array. The camera should then rotate to face the selected random waypoint and start moving towards it.

Once the camera has reached the waypoint, it should wait 3 seconds before rotating to face and move towards the next random waypoint.

The problem I have is in `Start()`. The camera does not rotate to face the first waypoint before it starts moving towards it. Instead, it moves towards the first waypoint backwards. Then, when it reaches the waypoint, it waits 3 seconds to rotate and move towards the next waypoint.

It's working fine except that the camera does not rotate to face the first selected random waypoint. It's moving to it backward without first rotating to face it.

Here's my code:

## The waypoints script

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    public GameObject player;
    public float speed = 5;
    public float WPradius = 1;
    public LookAtCamera lookAtCam;

    private int current = 0;
    private bool rot = false;

    public void Init()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Target");

        if(waypoints.Length > 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(RotateFacingTarget(waypoints[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length)].transform));
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (waypoints.Length > 0)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(waypoints[current].transform.position, transform.position) < WPradius)
            {
                current = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length);
                rot = false;
                StartCoroutine(RotateFacingTarget(waypoints[current].transform));

                if (current >= waypoints.Length)
                {
                    current = 0;
                }
            }

            if (rot)
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[current].transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator RotateFacingTarget(Transform target)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

        lookAtCam.target = target;
        rot = true;
    }
}
```

## The look at camera script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LookAtCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    //values that will be set in the Inspector
    public Transform target;
    public float RotationSpeed;

    //values for internal use
    private Quaternion _lookRotation;
    private Vector3 _direction;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //find the vector pointing from our position to the target
        if (target)
        {
            _direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;

            //create the rotation we need to be in to look at the target
            _lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_direction);

            //rotate us over time according to speed until we are in the required rotation
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, _lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you calling `Waypoints.Init()` from somewhere? I'm not seeing where `waypoints` variable has any values set.

Comment: @Eliasar Yes I have a third script attached to empty GameObject that generate the waypoints and there after generating the waypoints I'm calling the Init() method.

Comment: As a point of nomenclature (naming convention) since this is run more than once, I would rename it to `RefreshWaypoints` instead of `Init`. Also, since you're refreshing it multiple times, your coroutine will fire multiple times instead of waiting to process. You might have multiple coroutines running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that `Waypoints.Init()` is being called and your `waypoints` variable has an array of 3.

- `Waypoints.Init()` starts a coroutine

  - Your coroutine waits 3 seconds
  - After 3 seconds, you set your camera target which `Slerp`s to face the position
- `Update` on its first frame says `waypoints.Length > 0 == true`

  - It's not close to its target, and `rot` is false, so it does not move

Now, you're waiting 3 seconds, not rotating, and not moving.

- Your coroutine's 3 second wait time is up and starts the rotation toward your target
- `rot` is now true at the start of your rotation, so your `Update` method starts moving toward the target as well

It would seem that your logic is off in how the order of operations works. If it needs to act as you describe, I suggest that you operate on the target differently.

I've implemented the following using an enum:

### Waypoints

```
public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] waypoints;
    private Transform currentWaypoint;

    private enum CameraState
    {
        StartRotating,
        Rotating,
        Moving,
        Waiting
    }

    private CameraState cameraState;

    public GameObject player;
    public float speed = 5;
    public float WPradius = 1;
    public LookAtCamera lookAtCam;

    private int current = 0;
    private bool isCameraRotating = false;

    void Start()
    {
        cameraState = CameraState.StartRotating;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        switch (cameraState)
        {
            // This state is used as a trigger to set the camera target and start rotation
            case CameraState.StartRotating:
            {
                // Sanity check in case the waypoint array was set to length == 0 between states
                if (waypoints.Length == 0)
                    break;

                // Tell the camera to start rotating
                currentWaypoint = waypoints[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length)].transform;
                lookAtCam.target = currentWaypoint;
                cameraState = CameraState.Rotating;

                break;
            }

            // This state only needs to detect when the camera has completed rotation to start movement
            case CameraState.Rotating:
            {
                if (lookAtCam.IsFinishedRotating)
                    cameraState = CameraState.StartMoving;

                break;
            }

            case CameraState.Moving:
            {
                // Move
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, currentWaypoint.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);

                // Check for the Waiting state
                if (Vector3.Distance(currentWaypoint.position, transform.position) < WPradius)
                {
                    // Set to waiting state
                    cameraState = CameraState.Waiting;

                    // Call the coroutine to wait once and not in CameraState.Waiting
                    // Coroutine will set the next state
                    StartCoroutine(WaitForTimer(3));
                }

                break;
            }
            case CameraState.Waiting:
                // Do nothing. Timer has already started
                break;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForTimer(float timer)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
        cameraState = CameraState.StartRotating;
    }

    public void RefreshWaypoints()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Target");
    }
}
```

### LookAtCamera

```
public class LookAtCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Values that will be set in the Inspector
    public Transform target;
    public float RotationSpeed;

    private float timer = 0.0f;
    public bool IsRotationFinished
    {
        get { return timer > 0.99f; }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (target != null && timer < 0.99f)
        {
            // Rotate us over time according to speed until we are in the required rotation
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,
                Quaternion.LookRotation((target.position - transform.position).normalized),
                timer);

            timer += Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your solution. The camera is never rotating facing the next target. It's moving to the next target but keep facing as it was in the start. It's just moving forward backward right left in straight lines depending where the next waypoint is.

Comment: Place some debug statements in `LookAtCamera` for the target, and also where the target is set in `Waypoints`. What do they tell you about the picked target?

Comment: I found what is the problem. In the LookAtCamera script on the line: if (target != null && timer < 0.99f) target is not null but the other condition timer is never less then 0.99f and therefore it's never get inside and make the rotation. Used a break point on this line and timer is all the timer bigger then 0.99f I also put a break point on the line inside the transform.rotation....and it's never get there. But I checked few times in a row and each time the timer value was bigger then 0.99f

Comment: Then set the time to 0.0 when you set the target. Make a method to reset it, or make a method that resets the timer and sets the target instead of setting target directly in Waypoints

Comment: Ok it seems to be working. I added a new method that get float and then set the timer to that float 0.0f but once the camera rotating and finished rotating facing the new target then it's waiting another 3 second or more before start moving.

Comment: Inside the case CameraState.StartRotating before setting the target to the camera I'm calling the method to reset the timer: lookAtCam.setTime(0.0f); then it's doing the rest of lines picking up random target and set it to the camera. But still after rotating it's waiting more then 3 seconds before start moving.